# C++ string class efficiency

Tags: c++, string, performance

I have an old string class I wrote years ago (before the standard library was so standard). It works OK but I suppose I should move into the 21th century on my latest project. What I was wondering was how efficient the standard library string class is. For instance if I pass a string to a function or simply assign it to another sting does it copy the data, or simply copy a pointer to the data.

In my old class I kept a reference count with the data and just copied the pointer.  If I did something that modified the string in place, I would check to see if its reference was 1. If it was 1 I could use the same string data area assuming the string didn't grow past it's original size. If it was greater than 1 I would copy the string data it before modifying it.

Does the standard library class do something similar (or hopefully better), or does it copy the data every time you pass strings around. I guess this could be implementation dependent.  I'm currently developing for windows, although I will probably port it later. Thanks

Comment: `std::string`s each own their own state, they never share states. It sounds like you want copy-on-write semantics (like [`QString`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html) does, but this isn't supported by the standard implementation.

Comment: Note that by passing references (when you don't want to modify the string) and by using move semantics (when you want to transfer ownership), you can avoid have to copy strings unless you actually want a copy in most cases. To answer the question, no it doesn't support copy-on-write but it also doesn't necessarily copy the data every time the string is passed around.

Comment: `std::string` will probably out perform yours under most circumstances due to the small string optimization. Move support etc. But you should profile and find out.

Comment: `std::string` is not allowed to use copy on write.  That said with C++11 and short string optimization `std::string` will work for a decent amount of situations.

Comment: How would you do copy-on-write when using c_str()?

Comment: @stark On those implementations, I would suspect that any change to the string would invalidate pointers returned by previous `c_str()` calls.

Comment: It's also worth noting that COW strings always have threading issues even when they appear to be used in a single threaded context. `std::string` has no such issue as it's explicitly not thread safe, but if passed to another thread a copy can (and should) be made assuming the developer didn't pass a pointer.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the point about COW strings. If both are not thread safe what's the difference?

Comment: @Jabberwock The difference is I can pass a COW string to a new thread by 'value' and think I'm being thread safe. With a `std::string` you are being thread safe because you are really getting a copy. This allows you to do things like having a non-`const` `data()` member in C++17 because you can be sure the buffer shouldn't be shared across threads if you're using value semantics.

Comment: If you make your COW string class thread safe, then you pay a high performance price when you use it in non-threaded situations.

Comment: OK well I'm lost, LOL!  I guess I'll just stick to what I have for now since it seams I can use it with a more brain dead programming style and not get into the worst case scenario of copping string data all over the place.  My code will only have 3 or so threads that are always running and I won't be passing strings between them. Thanks for your input guys.

Comment: @Jabberwock word of warning, be very very careful if you use COW strings in a threaded environment. You're likely causing undefined behavior.

Comment: just measure the performance, replace with std::string, measure again, compare. std::string gives small string optimization, but no copy-on-write.

Comment: Well, with `std::string`, you want to move instead of copy where possible. With a COW string, you always addref.

Comment: @Jabberwock If your current reference count is not thread safe, you should probably just never, ever use your class for anything. Lots of modern code uses threads and making functions use classes that will never, ever work right with code that's threaded seems like a trap waiting for someone to fall into. Values should have value semantics. Imagine how hard `int` would be to work with if passing an `int` modified it. As for performance, frequent modification kills cache performance -- every pass is a modify .. yuck!

Answer (score 2):

Small string optimisation has proven to be more effective in most contexts than COW. It's not a guaranteed win though; it can depend a lot on exactly how it's being used. However I would argue that you can always use `std::shared_ptr<std::string>` to implement your COW class and save yourself a lot of manual memory management crap.

Bottom line is, `std::string` is *probably* better but the details here can swing it. Try it out but be careful.

Answer (score 0):

With the bloated interface of `std::string` you get copy-on-**potential**-write, which is a lot less efficient.

For example in `char& c = s[i]; c = 'a';` the assignment to `c` is not allowed to throw `bad_alloc` if needing to creating a separate COW item when `s` happens to be shared. So we must un-share the string in every non-const call to `s[i]`, just-in-case.

In practice, this limits the sharing potential *a lot*, while also adding lots of `if (shared) unshare();` code to many string member functions. In multi-threaded code, this is a real performance killer as the `unshare()` will have to lock the object while un-sharing.